# Not possible to connect with http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Tags: django, server

I am trying to connect with the server 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/

(Django)
but the only result is like below...:

[see print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTAQN.png)

any ideas what went wrong?

Comment: have you started the development server?

Comment: How are you starting your django app?

Comment: being on activated virtual environment , in the project folder, I was calling the following line in Anaconda Prompt: "python manage.py runserver"

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you need to change your allowed_hosts variable in your settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']
```